How to patch javascript code in SXA SearchTheme
I am using Sitecore XP 10.2 with SXA.
I encountered an issue in sxa search checklist filter.
I have a facet that contains the '&' character and this is breaking the filtering of results.
This seems to be an old known issue not yet fixed and there is also another post on the same topic here on stack exchange: a user suggested a way to patch the bug by directly fixing javascript code part of the sxa SearchTheme, among the Base Themes.
Waiting for the issue to be addressed and the fix released by Sitecore SXA Developers (maybe in the future?) is there a more "Sitecore" way to patch? A best practice? Meaning, it is possible to extend the theme and overwrite the bugged code in some way?
